# Detecting duplicates formatted as text

Tags: excel, vba

I need a function to detect duplicates formatted as text.

This cannot distinguish between "46.500" and"46.5000". CountIf probably compares cells as numbers. These cells are formatted as text. I tried to add an apostrophe prior the numbers.

```
Function check_duplicates(column As String)
LastRow = Range(column & "65536").End(xlUp).row
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(column & "1:" & column & LastRow), Range(column & x).Text) > 1 Then
        check_duplicates = x  ' return row with a duplicate
        x = 1   
    Else
         check_duplicates = 0
    End If
Next x
End Function
```

Does anyone know how to force CountIf to compare cells as strings or other way to check for duplicates in VBA?

Comment: Does this help?
http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=985

Comment: Yes, this one works too but the source code is a bit intimidating :-) Thank you.

Comment: Yah, it was supposed to be a copy/paste thing. All the extra stuff is to allow for undo/redo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually find ado useful in such circumstances.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object

strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT F2, Count(F2) AS CountF2 FROM [Sheet1$] " _
  & "GROUP BY F2 HAVING Count(F2)>1 "
rs.Open strSQL, cn

s = rs.GetString
MsgBox s

'' Or
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Little bit complicated for seemingly simple task but works great.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the "text" cells are textual representations of numbers, then the following change will work:

```
Function check_duplicates(column As String)
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim x As Long

    lastrow = Range(column & "65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(column & "1:" & column & lastrow), Val(Range(column & x).Text)) > 1 Then
            check_duplicates = x  ' return row with a duplicate
            x = 1
        Else
         check_duplicates = 0
        End If
    Next x
End Function
```

It coerces the value of the criteria cell to a value by the use of the `Val` function

Comment: Unfortunately some of these texts are not numbers. These are product codes and sometimes they have alphabetical in them (suffixes, prefixes or in the middle)

Comment: In that case you can actually check if the row being checked is a numeric value or not. If its numeric use the formula given by Lunatik, otherwise use the formula what you are using currently using.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to check for duplicates using VBA - but in case a worksheet formula would help someone (and maybe seemed difficult?), here's an array formula that will notify you whether or not the cells in a given range are unique.

```
=IF(MAX(COUNTIF(B$3:B$100,B3:B100))>1,"List has duplicates","List is unique")
```

> - Since this is a worksheet **array formula**, instead of hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish entering the formula, you'll need to use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>**.   (More info in the links below.)

This (obviously) looks at range `B3:B100`. You can change it to whatever, but note that the `$` exists in one part but not the other.  Also, if you use it on large ranges (2000+ cells), it might take a few seconds to update every time you change a cell.

Alternatively, you could place and remove the formula programmatically with VBA, using the [`FormulaArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray) property of the [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) object.

More info from Microsoft about array formulas [**here**](https://support.office.com/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) and [**here**](https://support.office.com/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) and limitations [**here**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/166342/description-of-the-limitations-for-working-with-arrays-in-excel).

Answer (score 0):

The CountIf function doesn't takes a formula as its second argument, so the second argument should be:

"=" & Range(column & x).Text

Answer (score 0):

Here is new version based on Remou's code. This one is little more versatile and works with MS Excel 2007.

```
Function check_duplicates(column As Integer)
' checks for duplicates in a column
' usage: column - numerical (A = 1, B=2 etc...)
' returns: "" - no duplicates, otherwise list of duplicates with numbers of occurrences

Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name

' connection string for Excel 2007
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & _
";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strcon

col = "F" & Trim(Str(column))

strsql = "SELECT " & col & ", Count(" & col & ") AS Count" & col & " FROM [" & strSheet & "$]" & _
"GROUP BY " & col & " HAVING Count(" & col & ")>1 "
rs.Open strsql, cn

If rs.BOF = True And rs.EOF = True Then
        check_duplicates = ""
    Else
        check_duplicates = rs.GetString
End If
End Function
```