# Excel VBA, compare multiple column values, color cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA in Excel and I'm having some trouble. I have 3 columns A, C, and F. I want to highlight only the cells in those columns if they match either of 2 conditions. Highlight any cells with duplicate values in column A, and then only highlight cells in column C and F if column C has a value of 99.99 and greater and Column F has anything but "Test" in the cell.

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim index As Integer
For index = 1 To 4
'Checks if any cells in Column C has value greater than 99.99 when Column F isn't "Test" or checks if multiple values exist in Column A (which I don't know)
If Range("C1") And Cell.Value > "99.99" And Range("F1") And Cell.Text <> "Current"  Then
'Highlighs both cell values Yellow (this is where I run into trouble)
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = vbYellow
End If
Next index
End Sub
```

Comment: Not able to understand the question completely, best way around would be to build IF conditions or similar logic in excel formula, and convert the same to vba using sheets("sheet1").range("a1").formula="=your formula here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just referring to your range wrong. `Cell` wasn't set. I couldn't see where you were referring to column A though.

Also, if you're using the built in color constants you should use `.Color` not ColorIndex.

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim index As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

'set the sheet to use
Set ws = Sheet1

    For index = 1 To 4

    'Checks if any cells in Column C has value greater than 99.99 when Column F isn't "Test" or checks if multiple values exist in Column A (which I don't know)
        If ws.Range("C" & index).Value > "99.99" And ws.Range("F" & index).Text <> "Current" Then
        'Highlighs both cell values Yellow (this is where I run into trouble)
        ws.Range("C" & index).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        ws.Range("F" & index).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If

    Next index

End Sub
```

On a side note. You may be better off looking at using Conditional formatting to achieve what you want rather than VBA.

There is a lot of tutorials about on the internet:

http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/03/13/excel-conditional-formatting-basics/

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/advancedexcel/tp/090822-excel-conditional-formatting-hub.htm

Comment: Thanks Same for your quick reply! If I needed to also highlight duplicate values in column A, what would that be? If ws.Range("A" & index).Value = ?????   Also, I wish I could use conditonal formatting, but unfortunately there's other coding that checks if a row has any highlighted cell color and if so, it hides it. With conditional formatting it ignores the color.

Comment: duplicate values in the whole of column A? If so you may want to look at `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` here is a stackoverflow question that may help you get the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492048/function-for-detecting-duplicates-in-excel-sheet